# Reading PDF Bookmarks in VB.NET using iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I am making a tool that scans PDF files and searches for text in PDF bookmarks and body text. I am using Visual Studio 2008 with VB.NET with iTextSharp.

How do I load bookmarks' list from an existing PDF file?

Comment: So far I have reached up to using PDFReader class, but can't figure out how to enumerate the bookmarks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you understand when you say "bookmarks".

**You want the outlines (the entries that are visible in the bookmarks panel):**

The [CreateOnlineTree](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=139) examples shows you how to use the `SimpleBookmark` class to create an XML file containing the complete outline tree (in PDF jargon, bookmarks are called outlines).

**Java:**

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
SimpleBookmark.exportToXML(list,
        new FileOutputStream(dest), "ISO8859-1", true);
reader.close();
```

**C#:**

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn);
var list = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    SimpleBookmark.ExportToXML(list, ms, "ISO8859-1", true); 
    ms.Position = 0;
    using (StreamReader sr =  new StreamReader(ms)) {
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }              
}
```

The `list` object can also be used to examine the different bookmark elements one by one programmatically (this is all explained in the official documentation).

**You want the named destinations (specific places in the document you can link to by name):**

Now suppose that you meant to say named destinations, then you need the `SimpleNamedDestination` class as shown in the [LinkActions](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=131) example:

**Java:**

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
HashMap<String,String> map = SimpleNamedDestination.getNamedDestination(reader, false);
SimpleNamedDestination.exportToXML(map, new FileOutputStream(dest),
        "ISO8859-1", true);
reader.close();
```

**C#:**

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
Dictionary<string,string> map = SimpleNamedDestination
      .GetNamedDestination(reader, false);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    SimpleNamedDestination.ExportToXML(map, ms, "ISO8859-1", true);
    ms.Position = 0;
    using (StreamReader sr =  new StreamReader(ms)) {
      return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

The `map` object can also be used to examine the different named destinations one by one programmatically. Note the `Boolean` parameter that is used when retrieving the named destinations. Named destinations can be stored using a PDF name object as name, or using a PDF string object. The `Boolean` parameter indicates whether you want the former (`true` = stored as PDF name objects) or the latter (`false` = stored as PDF string objects) type of named destinations.

Named destinations are predefined targets in a PDF file that can be found through their name. Although the official name is named destinations, some people refer to them as bookmarks too (but when we say bookmarks in the context of PDF, we usually want to refer to outlines).

Comment: Huh? Why the downvote? It would help if the person who downvoted it explained what is wrong with my answer. I gave Java/C# examples on how to retrieve outlines and named destinations, two concepts that could be interpreted as "bookmarks". What more can one expect?

Comment: OK, well the -1 made me improve the answer a little bit, e.g. explaining what the `Boolean` parameter when extracting named destinations is about.

Comment: By bookmarks I meant outlines, so first part of the answer points me to right direction. However for me it is of no use converting to XML as I just need to perform a search, so I will be using the "list" object to enumerate through bookmarks. As iText documentation is divided between class reference and a book (which I do not have), I needed a start point. Cheers!

P.S. I didn't downvote.

Comment: The XML will give you an insight on the elements in the `list`. This list should be interpreted as a tree where the value of each entry can be a leaf (e.g. a title) or a branch (e.g a new series of "kids"). Maybe the person who downvoted the answer was the same person who downvoted the question...

Comment: Downvoting for good answer can happen unintentionally (rare), accidentally clicking the wrong arrow because of momentary distraction; or the downvoter just had a bad day (also rare)... I once downvoted accidentally an answer that I know for sure I had intended to upvote. Discovered it a few days later by checking my own voting history. Of course I reverted that vote and made it an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still searching the vb.net solution, trying to simplify, I have a large amount of pdf created with reportbuilder and with documentmap I automatically add a bookmarks "Title". So with iTextSharp I read the pdf and extract just the first bookmark value:

```
    Dim oReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PdfFileName)
    Dim list As Object
    list = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(oReader)
    Dim string_book As String
    string_book = list(0).item("Title")
```

It is a little help very simple for someone searching a start point to understand how it works.