# How to extract bookmarks from a PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-parsing

When I open a PDF in a PDF viewer, I see a series of bookmarks on the left side of the actual document. The information shown there doesn't seem to make part of the actual content of the document: it isn't printed, it's not present on a specific page.

How can I extract these bookmarks using Java?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as an iText question when you're talking about PdfBox. Please complete the sentence *I have pdf viewed in document viewer where the left side of the view.* Are you referring to the bookmarks panel? Are you referring to the panel with the tags of a Tagged PDF? Metadata usually isn't shown to the left in a PDF viewer. Metadata is shown when you select File > Document Properties.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie . Sorry for this.  Ya i do see some information present in bookmark panel .  I tried with both PdfBox and Itext but i couldnt those information. Also the information present in book mark is not present anywhere in the Pdf text

Comment: The viewer from PDFBox doesn't display metadata. You can see it with the PDFDebugger commandline tool (if that was your question). https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#pdfDebugger 
Your question is really unclear, about whether you are asking "how to" or whether it is about an error / unwanted behaviour. You should really work on the question to explain what you want to do / what you did do / what happened instead.

Comment: The information present in the bookmarks doesn't have to be present in the text. These are separate things. PDFBox does have methods to read the bookmarks: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/PrintBookmarks.java

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Tilman Hausherr  I am able to complete the task.

Answer (score 5):

The OP question asked for a solution with Java.

However, this is may be a topic of more general interest to people who have to handle PDFs. So my answer offers a *command line* solution: `mutool`.

**`mutool`** is a command line utility bundled with the **[MuPDF viewer](http://mupdf.com/)** software, written by the same company which gave us Ghostscript.

Its latest version includes the ***`show`*** sub-command, which can be used to print `outlines` (that is in PDF technical parlance what the OP and the Adobe UI call "bookmarks"), amongst other specific items of interest from a PDF:

```
$ mutool show PDF32000_2008.pdf outlines

  Document management — Portable document format — Part 1: PDF 1.7  1
  Contents Page 3
  Foreword  6
  Introduction  7
  1 Scope   9
  2 Conformance 9
    2.1 General 9
    2.2 Conforming readers  9
    2.3 Conforming writers  9
    2.4 Conforming products 10
  3 Normative references    10
  4 Terms and definitions   14
  5 Notation    18
  6 Version Designations    18
  7 Syntax  19
    7.1 General 19
    7.2 Lexical Conventions 19
        7.2.1 General   19
        7.2.2 Character Set 20
        7.2.3 Comments  21
  [....]
```

(Output was shortened.) The original PDF document (the official PDF-1.7 specification), contains this page as the ToC:

[image: Original Document]

You can clearly see, how the `/Outlines` contents are different (but similar) to the included table of contents page.

Here is how the outlines ("bookmarks") are displayed in Adobe Reader XI:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please download the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). In that book, you'll find the answer to many questions, including to the question [Reading PDF Bookmarks in VB.NET using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739820/reading-pdf-bookmarks-in-vb-net-using-itextsharp)

The coolest way to extract bookmarks, is by creating an XML file that shows the bookmarks in a nice hierarchical way:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
SimpleBookmark.exportToXML(list,
    new FileOutputStream(dest), "ISO8859-1", true); 
reader.close();
```

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
I am able to get the bookmarks using PDFBOx and iText.

Could anyone please tell me how to get this in PdfLib?

Comment: Why would you down-vote my answer? You explicitly asked to extract bookmarks using iText (or PdfBox or PdfLib). I initially downvoted your question because it wasn't clear. Then you clarified your question, after which I edited your question. Subsequently, I retracted my down vote as the question was in better shape after my edits.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the bookmark content from a PDF file with Java you can use the pCOS interface of PDFlib+PDI 9. A sample code is included in the pCOS Cookbook:
http://www.pdflib.com/en/pcos-cookbook/interactive-elements/bookmarks/