# Get bookmark coordinates in PDF

Tags: c#, itext

I'm working in placing signature image to PDF at exact place. In PDF I add with report tool bookmark so I could know where to place signature image. Problem is I don't know how to get bookmark coordinates. Is it with `ITextsharp` possible?

------>EDIT
Picture of bookmark

[image]

----->EDIT

Solution is:

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(GlobalVars.PdfFile);
        IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(pdfReader);
        string BookmarkID = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < bookmarks.Count; j++)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(bookmarks[i].Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString());
            string s = bookmarks[j].Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString();
            if (bookmarks[j].Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString() == "##PODPIS##")
            {
                BookmarkID = bookmarks[j].Values.ToArray().GetValue(1).ToString();
            }


        }

        var map = SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(pdfReader, true);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in map)
        {
            if (entry.Key.ToString() == BookmarkID)
            {
                string[] LocationArray = entry.Value.Split(null);
                GlobalVars.SignatuePageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(LocationArray[0]);
                GlobalVars.SignatureX = float.Parse(LocationArray[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                GlobalVars.SignatureY = float.Parse(LocationArray[3], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Define "bookmarks". Are you talking about what is officially named "Outlines" or are you talking about "Named destinations"? If you are talking about "Outlines", then what you call a "bookmark" can be implemented as an explicit destination (which would solve your problem), as a named destination, but also as another action, e.g. JavaScript (which would make your question difficult to answer). In short: your question is incomplete. If you don't share a PDF with us, we can't help you, because "bookmarks" could mean different things in the context of PDF. Please be more accurate.

Comment: I don't know if it is outline or is it named destination. I add picture to post maybe you could figure it out.

Comment: Based on the picture, we now know that it's an outline, but we still don't know which type of outline. Please share the PDF so that we can investigate. Or open the PDF in [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups) and show us how the Outline is composed. Or why don't you read the [documentation](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) where you'll find answers such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739820/reading-pdf-bookmarks-in-vb-net-using-itextsharp

Comment: I found coordinates. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Read up on bookmarks, the action that happens when you click on one isn't always a simple destination. As along as you are creating the bookmark for later consumption, you're OK, but without sufficient guards for the general cases, you're creating future issues. A bookmark can have an entire tree of actions that occur in succession when it is clicked.

Comment: It is not issue for us beacuse we are creating bookmark with only one action "goto".

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(GlobalVars.PdfFile);
        IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(pdfReader);
        string BookmarkID = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < bookmarks.Count; j++)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(bookmarks[i].Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString());
            string s = bookmarks[j].Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString();
            if (bookmarks[j].Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString() == "##PODPIS##")
            {
                BookmarkID = bookmarks[j].Values.ToArray().GetValue(1).ToString();
            }


        }

        var map = SimpleNamedDestination.GetNamedDestination(pdfReader, true);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in map)
        {
            if (entry.Key.ToString() == BookmarkID)
            {
                string[] LocationArray = entry.Value.Split(null);
                GlobalVars.SignatuePageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(LocationArray[0]);
                GlobalVars.SignatureX = float.Parse(LocationArray[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                GlobalVars.SignatureY = float.Parse(LocationArray[3], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
            }
        }
```